# Record audio and play it simultaneously

Tags: android, audio, record

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this...sorry in advance if it is wrong.

Currently I have an app that can record audio with the mic and afterwards plays the file.
What I am wondering now is if it is possible to play the recorded file directly. So like a phone call, only that the file is always on one device and is recorded and played from the same device.

Is that possible? Maybe with streaming or something? Unfortunately I am a noob.

I would be very happy about an answer and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, to play the audio directly with a `stream method`. The data will be saved in background. To get basic knowledge I suggest to take a look at these examples, explained by the `android-studio` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer). This is a taff project as a beginner. Start step by step. First try to record `audio`, then stream with `mediaPlayer` and saving it. And the final step is all together. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it this way

Comment: You are welcome, could you tick that question as correct, that other can see the answer. Thank you :) Good luck!